# Question on relative homology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have this:

> $\ \ $ $3)$ Assume now that each critical point of $\varphi$ in $K_c$ is isolated in $X$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be such that $c-\epsilon >b$ and $c$ is the only critical value of $\varphi$ in $[c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon]$. Consider the exact sequence $$\ldots\to H_m(\varphi^{c+\epsilon},\varphi^{c-\epsilon})\overset\partial\to H_{m-1}(\varphi^{c-\epsilon},\phi)\overset{i_*}\to H_{m-1}(\varphi^{c+\epsilon},\phi)\to\ldots.$$ There exists a chain $\tau$ such that $\sigma=\partial\tau$ and $|\tau|\subset\varphi^{c+\epsilon}$. Thus $[\sigma]=0$ in $H_{m-1}(\varphi^{c+\epsilon},\phi)$. On the other hand, if $[\sigma]=0$ in $H_{m-1}(\varphi^{c-\epsilon},\phi)$, there exists a chain $\tau$ such that $\sigma=\partial\tau$ and $|\tau|\subset\varphi^{c-\epsilon}$. But this contradicts, the definition of $c$. Thus $[\sigma]$ is a nonzero element of $\operatorname{Ker}i_*$. By exactness, $H_m(\varphi^{c+\epsilon},\varphi^{c-\epsilon})\neq\{0\}$. The conclusion then follows from Theorem 8.1. $\tag*{$\square$}$

Where $|\tau|$ is the support of the chain $\tau$. I don't understand the first part, why $[\sigma]=0$ in $H_{m-1}(\phi^{c+\varepsilon},\emptyset)$ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exactness of the sequence tells us that $i^*\circ\partial=0$.

Since $\sigma=\partial\tau$ with $|\tau|\subset\varphi^{c+\varepsilon}$ then 
the class of $\sigma$ in $H_{m-1}(\varphi^{c+\varepsilon},\phi)$ is just the image $i^*$ of $\partial[\tau]=[\partial\tau]$, hence it's $0$.

$$[\sigma]=[\partial\tau]=i^*(\partial[\tau])=(i^*\circ\partial)[\tau]=0$$

Be careful that the $[.]$ notation is used indifferently for different quotient spaces.

Comment: thank you , you are the best mouaaaaaah lol

Comment: Hello, i want to ask you a question please , is $\ker\partial =H_m(\phi^{c+\varepsilon},\phi^{c-\varepsilon})$ thank you

Comment: We have $\{0\}\subsetneq\mathrm{Ker}\partial\subset H_m\left(\varphi^{c+\varepsilon},\varphi^{c-\varepsilon}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

This follows directly from the exactness of the sequence you wrote down.

Comment: how the exactness? i don't understand

Comment: i thik that is right this is come directly from the exactness

Comment: I was having a life, I suppose.

Comment: i'm sorry ^_^ , i don't know if you can help me for this: if $E=Y\oplus Z$ and if $S^{m-1}$ is the sphere on $Y$ ($\dim Y =m $) why  $H_{m-1}(E \setminus Z)\simeq H_{m-1}(S^{m-1})$ please thank you

Comment: Please ask this as a new question and make sure to define all spaces you write down.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586972/relative-homology